# Duplicate value in Json.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am working on a project using Asp.Net Web API. This API will make use of another API, let call it point-B.

The response from point-B will be as below and deserialize into Web API as I need to change some information in it and later serialize it again in Web API.

```
{
"Row": [
    {
        "key": "MjAxMy0xMQ==",
        "Cell": [
            {
                "column": "Y291bnQ6ZGFlbW9u",
                "timestamp": 1385195582067,
                "$": "MTE1"
            },
            {
                "column": "Y291bnQ6a2Vybg==",
                "timestamp": 1385195582067,
                "$": "MQ=="
            },
            {
                "column": "Y291bnQ6dXNlcg==",
                "timestamp": 1385195582067,
                "$": "MA=="
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my mapping.

```
public class RowEntry
{
    [JsonProperty("Row")]
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    private string _key;
    public string Key
    {
        get { return Base64Converter.ToUTF8(_key); }
        set
        {
            _key = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Cell")]
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "column")]
    private string _column;
    public string Column
    {
        get
        {
            return Base64Converter.ToUTF8(_column);
        }

        set
        {
            _column = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$")]
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return Base64Converter.ToUTF8(_value);
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller I have

```
// Get JSON from point-B
var response = await _client.GetStringAsync(BuildUri(table, startDate, endDate));
// Parse the result into RowEntry object
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RowEntry>(response);
// This should return the RowEntry object as JSON as I'm using Web API here
return results;
```

This should return a new JSON which only have elements as per my classes above. However, it seems that it also contains JSON from the first request from point-B.

```
{
"Row": [
    {
        "Key": "decoded value here",
        "key": "MjAxMy0xMQ==",
        "Cell": [
            {
                "Column": "decoded value here",
                "column": "Y291bnQ6ZGFlbW9u",
                "timestamp": 1385195582067,
                "Value": "decoded value here",
                "$": "MTE1"
            },
            // abbreviated
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm quite confused how it could be that way since I am serializing `RowEntry` and how could I fix this?

Comment: This is happening because of the `JsonProperty` attribute on the private fields. Do you need to switch the name of $ to value? If you're ok with $, this could be handled pretty easily.

Comment: I can't use the $ since when it get passed to the view, it clashed with jQuery $. But you're right, it is because of the private fields and I need to add `JsonIgnore` attribute. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `[JsonIgnore]` to the public properties for which you have decorated the corresponding private member variables with `[JsonProperty]`.  Json.Net does not implicitly know that a particular private member variable corresponds to a particular public property, so on serialization it is going to include both unless you tell it not to.

Revised classes:

```
public class Row
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    private string _key;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Key
    {
        get { return Base64Converter.ToUTF8(_key); }
        set { _key = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Cell")]
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "column")]
    private string _column;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Column
    {
        get { return Base64Converter.ToUTF8(_column); }
        set { _column = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timestamp")]
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$")]
    private string _value;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return Base64Converter.ToUTF8(_value); }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```